# MoPub advertisement

Tags: android, mopub

While integrating MoPub SDK in my app, I followed instructions line by line given at https://github.com/mopub/mopub-client/wiki/IntegrationHowToAndroid   but still I am getting an error:

```
 import com.mopub.mobileads.*;  is unresolved.
```

What mistake I am committing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the SDK and make sure that you include it in you project

Comment: thanks for ur answer Flynn. First I imported mopub-mopub-client-af712a9\Android  in my package explorer. then I add it in my project . still it is giving error.

Answer (score 0):

This is Franklin from MoPub. As Flynn said, you will have to edit your manifest file to have the proper permissions for the MoPub SDK.

Can you make sure you follow the instructions here:

- https://github.com/mopub/mopub-client/wiki/IntegrationHowToAndroid

Additionally, we have a knowledge base you can reference here:

- http://help.mopub.com/

If those don't help you solve the problem, feel free to email support@mopub.com. We're pretty good about responding and we'll make sure you're taken care of.